# Backbone: what events should i listen to

Tags: backbone.js

I created a view, that's listening to a collection. The models of this collections get replaced all at once. I want the view to be rendered as rarely as possible.

View:

```
BoxContent = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        console.log("BoxContent initializing");
        this.el = options.el;
        this.collection = options.collection;
        this.collection.on("add", this.update, this);
        this.collection.on("reset", this.update, this);
    },

    update: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        document.getElementById('boxContentHeader').innerHTML = localStorage.activeBox;
        console.log("BoxContent rendering");
        var temp = _.template(maincontemp,{boxFolder: this.collection});
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append(temp);
        this.$el.trigger("create");
    },

    reset: function()
    {
        this.render();
    },

    close: function(){
        //console.log("off-logging clickListener");
        //this.collection.off();
        //$(this.el).off();
    }
});
```

To update the collection I create an array of models, reset the collection and put the new array to the collection. I need to listen to reset, to make an empty collection beeing rendered.
I don't fetch the data from a restful-server.

Are there other ways to listen to changes to the collection?

EDIT:

One more question: Although I just add one array of models to the collection, is backbone calling the add event for each of the models inside of this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) in the docs. You can listen to all of the events which have the argument `collection` in the arguments.

- `add - (model, collection, options)` — when a model is added to a collection.
- `remove - (model, collection, options)` — when a model is removed from a collection.
- `reset - (collection, options)` — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.
- `sort - (collection, options)` — when the collection has been re-sorted.
- `destroy - (model, collection, options)` — when a model is destroyed.
- `request - (model_or_collection, xhr, options)` — when a model or collection has started a request to the server.
- `sync - (model_or_collection, resp, options)` — when a model or collection has been - successfully synced with the server.
- `error - (model_or_collection, resp, options)` — when model's or collection's request to remote server has failed.
- `all` – this special event fires for any triggered event, passing the event name as the first argument.

Comment: is it common to add an array of models to a collection?
or is it better to add model by model?

Comment: Both are fine, this is from the official documentation of `collection.reset`: *Adding and removing models one at a time is all well and good, but sometimes you have so many models to change that you'd rather just update the collection in bulk.*

Comment: Thanks, so I go on with my array.